# Moving right immediately pushes div far off screen region

Tags: javascript

When I attempt to move the div (tank) to the right ONLY in the first "movement command", and only in that direction, I come across in issue whereby my div shoots off a few thousand pixels to the right, way off of the screen region.  Was hoping someone would assist me to see why this is.

```
function animate() {
    var tank = document.getElementById("tank");

    tank.style.marginLeft="360px";
    tank.style.marginTop="440px";

    window.xpos = tank.style.marginLeft;
    window.ypos = tank.style.marginTop;

    window.x = xpos.replace("px","");
    window.y = ypos.replace("px","");

    document.onkeydown = checkKey;

    function checkKey(e) {

        e = e || window.event;

        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            if (x > 0) {
                x = x - 20;
                tank.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            }
        } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            if (x < 70) {
                x = x + 20;
                tank.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
            }
        } else if (e.keyCode == '38') {
            if (y > 0) {
                y = y - 20;
                tank.style.marginTop = y + "px";
            }
        } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
            if (y < 440) {
                y = y + 20;
                tank.style.marginTop = y + "px";
            }
        }
    }

    checkKey(e);
}

window.lives = 3;

function destroy() {
    if (lives != 0) {
        alert("Life Lost!");
        lives--;
        window.collision == false;
        animate();
    } else {
        alert("Try Again!");
    }
}

window.collision = true;

function state() {
    if (collision == false) {
        window.state = 1;
    } else if (collision == true) {
        window.state = 0;
    }

    return state;
}

state();

if (state == 1) {   
    animate();
} else {
    destroy();
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but you may want to think about replacing that complex if/elseif statement with a `switch(n){...}` function.

Comment: Not really utilised the switch case function yet, but will give it a go once I've figured out the issue, thanks!

Comment: It's pretty wonderful. I started using it earlier this year and it has yet to cause any issues. Check it out here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Thanks!  Just got to find out this issue first, really makes no sense. Not keyboard related (I have 2 and happens on both), not browser based, tried on multiple...margin-left="36020px" if I hit it from the get go, but if I hit left, up or down first and then right, right works every time.  Really rather confusing me

Answer (score 0):

You think you are doing a math operation but what you really are doing a string concatenation. In Javascript "360"-20 equals 340 because in this case the string is converted to a number and then an arithmetic subtraction is performed with both numeric values, however a different set of rules apply for the plus operator: in this case "360"+20 yields "36020" because the number is converted to a string and then both strings are concatenated.

Do this:

```
window.x = Number(xpos.replace("px",""));
window.y = Number(ypos.replace("px",""));
```